# Skip the last element in an array and return all other elements C#

Tags: c#, arrays, skip

I would like to return all elements but the last element. I looked at maybe using the Skip() method but got confused.
Can anyone help me out please?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

You can't use `Skip()` in this case but you must use [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

```
var result = list.Take(list.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Take`:

```
list.Take(list.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) for this:

```
var results = theArray.Take(theArray.Length - 1);
```

This will let you enumerate all elements except the last in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var array = ...;
var arrayExceptLasElement = array.Take(array.Length-1);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### Update with **.NET Standard 2.1** (2018+)

You can now do this directly with LINQ's [`SkipLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=net-7.0) like this:

```cs
var xs = new List<string>() {"A","B","C"};
var firstPart = xs.SkipLast(1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", firstPart)); // A,B
```

[**Demo in DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/La1Oz8)